# Remove My Documents junction points?

Tags: windows-7, ntfs, symbolic-link

AT home, I have a few notebooks of different vendors. All have Windows 7.

On a few of them, there are NTFS junction points in my home directory.

For example:

C:\Users\xxx\Anwendungsdaten (Anwendungsdaten is German for AppData)

or

C:\Users\xxx\Eigene Dateien (Eigene Dateien is German for My Documents)

These junction points seem to be backward compatibility links, so that Windows XP applications still work, I assume.

However, at other Windows 7 computers, these junction points do not exist. Instead, Windows automatically "renames" the folder "Documents" to "Eigene Dokumente"; only in Tools like TotalCommander, I can see their true name.

I have a backup solutions and tools which have problems with this junction points. Is it safe to remove these junction points? Why are they available in only a few Windows installations? I would love to get rid of them...

Comment: Are they all running the latest windows patches? Are you using the same settings to view the folders?

Comment: @Seth Yes. All have the latest Windows patches. I am using TotalCommander (the same version at every computer) to see the "real" folder contents. At one computer, there are these hardlinks, and on the other computer not.

Comment: Are you able to see the "ProgramData" folder on both? If not it could be that one has Configuration » Display » Show hidden/system files checked an the other has not. If that is not it (I'm guessing here) that one installation uses a MUI and the other one does not.

Comment: No. MUI is enabled on both.

Comment: My guess would still be that it's a display setting. On the explorer it would be "Hide protected operating system files" that decide whenever or not I'm able to see those junctions. You could try to run `dir /x /a` to see whenever one of the installations might be using symlinks instead of junctions. That would be one possible explanation.

Comment: `dir /x /a` shows "AppData" as a folder (<DIR>) and "Anwendungsdaten" as a <LINK>. My other computers don't have any <LINK> in the user's folder. All non-Explorer Applications show these symbolic Links and some of them are confused (because they follow the links and turn in an endless loop)

Comment: Those links should not loop. You will get the same directory multiple times but you wouldn't get in a loop. Those junctions also exist on englisch versions. My guess is that you used different installation medias/methods (upgrade from XP?) and hence different base versions to install those machines and/or display settings. As such you would get different behavior. If you don't have any software that relies on them you could probably remove them. Make a backup, test and restore. Check [this](http://www.itninja.com/blog/view/reparse-points-and-symbolic-links-a-windows-7-all-points-bulletin)

Answer (score 0):

This is also true today for `Windows-11`.

Only thing is to make sure it is indeed a `Junction` you are deleting and when deleting a junction you have to deleted it with the full path.

Here is a one-liner to *recursively* remove **all** junctions! So please check what junctions it will catch before using.

```
# Check:

(Get-ChildItem . -Force -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.LinkType -eq "Junction" -and $_.Attributes -match "ReparsePoint" }) | Select $_.FullName

# Remove: 
(Get-ChildItem . -Force -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.LinkType -eq "Junction" -and $_.Attributes -match "ReparsePoint" }) | Select $_.FullName | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse

# NOTE: ^ You need $_ there
```